# HTML5 Canvas -- Drawing a game level, overlapping previously drawn rectangles

Tags: arrays, html, canvas, drawing

I've been hacking away at this problem for the past three hours and cannot figure out where I went wrong.  Basically, I'm trying to draw a tile-based "level" for a little game.  As I understand it, the canvas should draw new rectangles on rectangles that have already been drawn.

I want to set it up so that there is one function that basically draws the background, and another function that draws the highlights on top of it.  The "highlights" are the top of a wall, and the background shows the side of it.  I want to draw the highlights on top because ideally I'd eventually like to draw a character in between them so the highlights would be on top of the character (as though it is behind the wall) while the background would be behind the character.

The background and shape of the level (without the highlight layer) looks like this: http://howtivity.com/leveldrawing

For some reason, I run into a lot of trouble trying to draw the highlights layer.  I want to offset the layer 50px above the background layer to give the impression of a three dimension wall, and I want any blank spaces where there is no wall to be transparent so the background still shows.  When I try drawing the layer with an almost identical function whose only difference is offsetting the layer 50px upward and set the no-wall fillStyle to transparent, it looks like this:  http://howtivity.com/leveldrawing/highlight.html

I've set it up to print text so I could diagnose where it might be wrong, but the text has shown up correctly.  I feel like I either misunderstood something about how the canvas is drawn, or have made some kind of error that I'm just not seeing.

```
<canvas height="600" width="1000" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; background: transparent;" id="background">
</canvas>

<script>
var level =
[
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
[1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1],
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
];

var bg = document.getElementById("background");
var bgContext = bg.getContext("2d");

var drawLevel = function() {
var levelDrawX = 0;
var levelDrawY = 0;

for (levelRow = 0; levelRow < 6; levelRow++) 
{   
  for (levelCol = 0; levelCol < 10; levelCol++) 
  {
    levelDrawX = (100 * levelCol); 
    if (level[levelRow][levelCol]==1) 
    {
        bgContext.fillStyle = "#ffe680";
        bgContext.fillRect(levelDrawX, levelDrawY, levelDrawX + 100, levelDrawY + 100);
    } else {
        bgContext.fillStyle = "#8dd35f";
        bgContext.fillRect(levelDrawX, levelDrawY, levelDrawX + 100, levelDrawY + 100);
    }

  }
levelDrawY += 100;
}
};

var drawHighlights = function() {
var levelDrawX = 0;
var levelDrawY = 0;

for (levelRow = 0; levelRow < 6; levelRow++) 
{   
  for (levelCol = 0; levelCol < 10; levelCol++) 
  {
    levelDrawX = (100 * levelCol); 
    if (level[levelRow][levelCol]==1) 
    {
        bgContext.fillStyle = "#000";
    } else {
        bgContext.fillStyle = "transparent";
    }
    bgContext.fillRect(levelDrawX, levelDrawY-50, levelDrawX+100, levelDrawY+50);

  }
levelDrawY += 100;
}
};


drawLevel();
drawHighlights();
```

Any help would be really appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was with the values required by fillRect.

I had typed them as if they were:

`fillRect(startX, startY, endX, endY);`

when actually they are:

`fillRect(startx, starty, width, height);`

Answer (score 2):

I admit to being a bit confused about what you want in your finished design.

Do you want your drawHighlights() to add a semi-transparent "shadows" to your drawLevel()?

If so, you can do that by setting the context's globalAlpha which is the level of opacity.

```
var drawHighlights = function() {

    var levelDrawX = 0;
    var levelDrawY = 0;

    bgContext.globalAlpha=0.8;

    for (levelRow = 0; levelRow < 6; levelRow++) 
    {   
      for (levelCol = 0; levelCol < 10; levelCol++) 
      {
        levelDrawX = (100 * levelCol); 
        if (level[levelRow][levelCol]==1) 
        {
            bgContext.fillStyle = "#777";
        } else {
            bgContext.fillStyle = "transparent";
        }
        //bgContext.fillText(levelCol, levelCol*100, 10+levelRow*100);
        bgContext.fillRect(levelDrawX, levelDrawY-50, levelDrawX+100, levelDrawY+50);

      }
      levelDrawY += 100;
    }

    bgContext.globalAlpha=1.0;

};
```

Comment: Thanks!  That's true...  I'll fix it on the example.  But, I'm still having trouble getting the two to draw correctly.  When the color in drawHighlights is set to "transparent" it stops drawing transparent spaces at level[2][2].  I'll upload a working demonstration.

Comment: Thanks again, sorry that I didn't explain it clearly.  No, I'm not trying to add semitransparent shadows.  Essentially I want to draw the background, and then overlay another layer of "highlights" on top of it.  The highlights would be the top of the wall, if viewed from above, and the background would be the side of the wall.  I want to offset the highlights 50px above the top of the shadows to give it an illusion of three dimensions.  I'll modify the demo slightly to show the background as it should be done: http://howtivity.com/leveldrawing

Comment: On top of the background there, I want to draw the same yellow shape, except a lighter shade of yellow, and offset 50px upward (the "highlight").

Comment: Mark E, adding your code (exactly as typed, to replace my original drawHighlights() ) for the transparent rectangles illustrates the problem: http://howtivity.com/leveldrawing/marke.html --  it should draw the same shape in shadows as the background, right?  But for some reason, it doesn't.  It gets hung up once it gets to [2][2] and only draws the grey from there.

Comment: The only way I've been able to get it to draw the shape correctly for the highlight is to replace the "transparent" value in the else with an actual color.  Then it draws the level shape correctly, but obviously overlaps the background where the green should be, like this: http://howtivity.com/leveldrawing/markewhite.html - the way it seems to do multiple passes as it gets farther toward the bottom right is weird, too.  I can't understand why it would draw the same rectangle multiple times as it gets farther in the array, but that seems like what it is doing.

Comment: Mark E, here's what I want it to look like: http://howtivity.com/leveldrawing/example.png

Comment: Damn, I just realized that the second two numbers in fillRect are width and height values.  I feel like a moron.  I think that's probably the issue.

Comment: Yup...  that worked: http://howtivity.com/leveldrawing/  It's always something stupid like that.  Thanks a lot for your responses.